# Comparar dos fechas en VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, date

quisiera saber como comparar dos fechas con .Net;
La fecha actual y una fecha insertada manualmente.

Formato: AAAA/MM/DD

Comment: Que has intentado para resolver el problema? Cual es el formato de fechas a comprar, String o un Objeto de tipo Fecha? Al comparar que esperas de resultado, saber cual es el mayor, la diferencia de dias, etc? Puedes leer las reglas para darte una idea de que espera la comunidad antes de responder una pregunta: es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo tanto en Google, como en SO hay mucha información al respecto, solo tiene que hacer el intento de buscar...

Asumiendo que el formato de la fecha es `DateTime` simplemente tome la parte de la fecha de cada una a través de la propiedad `Date` y compare las dos:

```
fechaActual.Date.CompareTo(fechaInsertada.Date)
```

Vea ejemplos:

```
if (DateTime.Compare(fechaActual, fechaInsertada) > 0) //La fecha actual es mayor que la fecha insertada.

if (DateTime.Compare(fechaActual, fechaInsertada) == 0) //La fecha actual y la fecha insertada son iguales.

if (DateTime.Compare(fechaActual, fechaInsertada) < 0)  //La fecha actual es menor que la fecha insertada.
```

O:

```
If fechaActual.Date < fechaInsertada.Date Then
```

> [Método DateTime.CompareTo (DateTime)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function MismoDiaHora(ByVal Fecha1 As Date, ByVal Fecha2 As Date) As Boolean
        MismoDiaHora = False
        If Dia(Fecha1) = Dia(Fecha2) And _
           Mes(Fecha1) = Mes(Fecha2) And _
           Ano(Fecha1) = Ano(Fecha2) And _
           Hora(Fecha1) = Hora(Fecha2) Then
            MismoDiaHora = True
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function MismoAno(ByVal Fecha1 As Date, ByVal Fecha2 As Date) As Boolean
        MismoAno = False
        If Ano(Fecha1) = Ano(Fecha2) Then
            MismoAno = True
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function MismoMes(ByVal Fecha1 As Date, ByVal Fecha2 As Date) As Boolean
        MismoMes = False
        If Mes(Fecha1) = Mes(Fecha2) Then
            MismoMes = True
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function MismoDia(ByVal Fecha1 As Date, ByVal Fecha2 As Date) As Boolean
        MismoDia = False
        If Dia(Fecha1) = Dia(Fecha2) And _
           Mes(Fecha1) = Mes(Fecha2) And _
           Ano(Fecha1) = Ano(Fecha2) Then
            MismoDia = True
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function FechaSolo(ByVal Fecha As Date) As Date
        On Error Resume Next
        FechaSolo = Dia(Fecha) & "/" & Mes(Fecha) & "/" & Ano(Fecha)
    End Function

    Public Function ErrorDate(ByVal Fecha As String) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim D As Date
        D = Fecha
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then ErrorDate = True Else ErrorDate = False
    End Function

    Public Function Ano(ByVal Fecha As Date) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Ano = Year(Fecha)
    End Function

    Public Function Dia(ByVal Fecha As Date) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Dia = Day(Fecha)
        If Len(Dia) = 1 Then Dia = "0" & Dia
    End Function

    Public Function DiaSemana(ByVal Fecha As Date) As Integer
        On Error Resume Next
        DiaSemana = vb.Weekday(Fecha, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)
    End Function

    Public Function Mes(ByVal Fecha As Date) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Mes = Month(Fecha)
        If Len(Mes) = 1 Then Mes = "0" & Mes
    End Function

    Public Function Hora(ByVal Fecha As Date) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Hora = Hour(Fecha)
        If Len(Hora) = 1 Then Hora = "0" & Hora
    End Function

    Public Function Minuto(ByVal Fecha As Date) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Minuto = Minute(Fecha)
        If Len(Minuto) = 1 Then Minuto = "0" & Minuto
    End Function

    Public Function Segundos(ByVal Fecha As Date) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Segundos = Second(Fecha)
        If Len(Segundos) = 1 Then Segundos = "0" & Segundos
    End Function
```